# significant difference between few averaged values

Tags: statistical-significance

I need to determine if one value is better significantly over others few values. I mean, I use a metric to measure different image segmentation methods, and I got these three values for that metric:

method 1: **4.23** (average of 3.06, 7.59, 2.04)
method 2: **4.17** (average of 2.89, 6.67, 2.95)
method 3: **2.63** (average of 1.98, 3.46, 2.45)

Is it possible to determine if the last value (method 3 = 2.63) differ significantly from the the other two methods. I understand there is few data, but it is all that I have.

I hope it was asked clear this time.

Thanks in advance, Jaime

Comment: Questions of statistical significance require information about the variability of the statistics you are using (your three values).  Therefore you need to edit this question to include such information.

Comment: I add information about three (averaged) values. I hope it helps to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample sizes are rather small, but you could cut up images into sub-parts in order to fix this issue. Perhaps visual inspection of the segmentation results will give you a hint in which sub-parts Method 3 is doing better than the others, and there you would see a greater difference in performance, if not in all such sub-parts of the image. (A sidenote, which may still be of relevance here: I don't know your segmentation method, but perhaps you could also use sub-parts of the image to choose any necessary parameters in an optimal way -- a common approach in image processing.)

Comment: Thanks @Cristian_Rau, I thinks your idea could work. I am going to split images to have a more information about every method's performance. I am comparing watershed and multiresolution segmentation methods versus a new method I am proposing.